Can floor joists be fastened directly to beams secured on sonotube piers with U-brackets
Let's say we have as the "foundation" for an oblong shed two rows of sonotube piers with U-brackets, and two wooden beams 6"x6" by 20' long bolted into the brackets, one beam on each row of sonotubes. It's like two balance beams at the Olympics gymnastics competition in parallel about a foot above the ground:
<---8'--->
||      ||
||      ||
||      ||
||      ||
||      ||
||      ||
||      ||
||      ||   

Q1: Can 2x6 floor-joists be hung between those beams from joist hangers in lieu of building a floor-system and placing it upon the beams?

Do not ask the same question again when your question is closed. You have been here long enough that you should know by now to edit your original closed question. Does this answer your question? When an outbuilding's floor joist system is mounted on concrete piers with brackets, how is the sill plate fastened to the perimeter?

I asked a different question. The first question was about a sill plate. This question is about joists.

And the first question involved a plywood-dimensional-lumber sandwich as the beam, and this question is about solid beams. A different set of considerations entirely in terms of fastening.   This question would have the joist hangers outside the envelope of the building with the ends of the foundation exposed, unlike in a cinderblock foundation.

I guess this would be called something like a "raised skid"?
